# How to implement SwipeRefreshLayout with the new Paging Library

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I got an activity that shows a list of items to the user and it uses the Paging Library. My problem is that I can't reload the list when user swipes down the screen so that it fetches data from the server again.

Here is my DataSource Factory:

```
public class CouponListDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {
    private CouponListDataSource dataSource;

    public CouponListDataSourceFactory(CouponRepository repository, String token, String vendorId) {
        dataSource = new CouponListDataSource(repository, token, vendorId);
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource create() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And here's how I create the PagedList

```
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(15)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();
LiveData<PagedList<Coupon>> couponsLiveData = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(dataSourceFactory, config).build();
```

Comment: simply invalidate your custom `DataSource`, what `DataSource` do you have?

Comment: @pskink I use PositionalDataSource. I call the invalidate method on my datasource but it does nothing. Should I do anything else after invalidating?

Comment: you use `PagedListAdapter`? whats your code? what does `PagedList#isDetached()` return?

Comment: Yes I do and I create it with the LivePagedListBuilder and return it from my viewmodel to my activity.

Comment: whats the code of `DataSource.Factory` you are passing to `LivePagedListBuilder` constructor? will you post **any** sources?

Comment: add `Log.d(TAG, "isInvalid: " + dataSource.isInvalid());` before returning from `CouponListDataSourceFactory#create` method, `invalidate()` your data source and watch the logcat

Comment: Yes it keeps printing "isInvalid: true" forever!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess my mistake is that I always return the old datasource in the create() method

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After calling the **mDataSource.invalidate()** method, mDataSource will be invalidated and the new DataSource instance will be created via DataSource.Factory.create() method, so its important to **provide new DataSource() instance every time inside DataSource.Factory.create() method, do not provide same DataSource instance every time**.

**mDataSource.invalidate() is not working,** because after invalidation, CouponListDataSourceFactory provides the same, already invalidated DataSource instance.

After modification CouponListDataSourceFactory will be looked like in below smple, and  call to **mCouponListDataSourceFactory.dataSource.invalidate() method will make a refresh**, **alternatively** instead of keeping dataSource instance inside the factory, we can call invalidate method on **LiveData< PagedList < CouponModel > >.getValue().getDataSource().invalidate()**

```
public class CouponListDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory {

private CouponListDataSource dataSource;

private CouponRepository repository;
private String token;
private String vendorId;

public CouponListDataSourceFactory(CouponRepository repository, String token, String vendorId) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.token = token;
    this.vendorId = vendorId;
}

@Override
public DataSource create() {
    dataSource = new CouponListDataSource(repository, token, vendorId);
    return dataSource;
}
}
```

Comment: i have try to invalidate the liveDataSource but when invalidate , adapter empty and display again after load finish. can you give me an idea when start refresh , adapter not empty , adapter will be replace after refresh finish

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question, I can't understand the main idea. However [here is the working example](https://github.com/RobertApikyan/PagingTutorial/tree/master) with Paging library and swipe to refresh

Comment: I want to understand how to apply refresh action on paging lib, i've try but look ugly, when action start Swipe Refresh my adapter empty

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I'v just pushed the new version of [Paging Demo app](https://github.com/RobertApikyan/PagingTutorial) , it get's the initial data by showing the swipe to refresh indicator

Comment: i've try like your code, but still not work
when `dataSource.invalidate` , adapter clear and display again after request finish,

Comment: After calling dataSource.invalidate() your adapter's data dissapear, and appear when request is finished, correct ? Am I understand it currently ?

Comment: ok... Is this behavior you are looking for ? [please check the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7k6-DAzYgk&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: yes, but why when first refresh scroll to bottom,
i've implement like your code before

Comment: The problem is in the ModelDataSource::loadInitial, I don't know why, but in this method the params.requestedStartPosition's value, sometimes is 9. So I'v just replace the row = params.requestedStartPosition with row = 0, since we always make initial loading with row = 0 parameter. This fix the scroll to bottom problem. May be there will be a better solution for this ... BTW I'v pushed the fixed code, you can find changes in ModelDataSource class

Comment: thanks a lot, I really appreciate to you,
i'll to try it in my code

Comment: sorry, but i've try modify your code with real api, adapter's data still disappear when refresh. this is the sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iLtTCX9Dy1lbF_kFEF40Q0dy_3rZiIhF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, First the reason. ModelDataSource.loadInitial() method is already called on the background thread, and it's expect that after loadInitial method invocation the data will be already fetched. So the replacement of caroutine's launch method to runblocking in your Network class will solve the problem. [Here is the Network class](https://gist.github.com/RobertApikyan/9e47a36e585c3b1b1ae308feb1136ce8). Another approach is to call retrofit api method synchronously, without redundant usage of caroutin inside loadInitial method,

Comment: thanks again, this is work
you have given me enlightenment

Answer (score 19):

Add a method in ViewModel class

```
 public void refresh() {

    itemDataSourceFactory.getItemLiveDataSource().getValue().invalidate();
}
```

and from the Activity/Fragment you can use

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> yourviewModel.refresh());
```

Hide the refresh layout when the reyclerView gets loaded

```
yourViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(this, allProposalModel -> {


        mAdapter.submitList(model);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); //here..


    });
```

Comment: after call invalidate the list don't load again. Should I do another action or it works itself?

Comment: In my case, seeing the log, it refreshes all data, but it is not being displayed. What else should I do?

Answer (score 2):

With new Paging 3 version the methods are moved to the `PagingDataAdapter` class

```
val adapter = PagingAdapter(R.layout.item_layout, ::ViewHolder) { i1, i2 -> i1.id == i2.id }

adapter.refresh() // to refresh from the network

adapter.retry() // to retry the current request if the load method returned LoadState.Error()
```