# Forcing Paging Library DataSource refresh

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-livedata, android-paging, android-architecture-lifecycle

In my ViewModel, I load data using

```
private val pagingConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(INITIAL_LOAD_SIZE_HINT)
    .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
    .build()

val notificationList = LivePagedListBuilder<Long, Notification>(dataSourceFactory, pagingConfig).build()
```

Which works fine. However, when my data changes, `LiveData<PagedList<Notification>>` does not get notified. Is there anything I can do to trigger `LiveData` refresh (the `ViewModel` knows when the change occurs).

Comment: For answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838015/2599596

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger data update using `invalidate()` method from the `DataSource`.

> When using the Paging Library, it's up to the data layer to notify the other layers of your app when a table or row has become stale. To do so, call `invalidate()` from the `DataSource` class that you've chosen for your app.

More information: [Notify when data is invalid](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#notify-data-invalid)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the .invalidate() route even before I posted but it does not do what I want it to do and it just clears the entire DataSource

Comment: @liminal and what you want to do?

Comment: `.invalidate()` should trigger a re-load of data. So if `invalidate()` doesn't work, then your data did not actually change underneath.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#notify-data-invalid

You have to call `dataSourceLiveData.value?.invalidate()`

I call it from my view like this:

> OnRefresh: View implements **SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener**

```
override fun onRefresh() {
    brewerViewModel.retry()
}
```

In define the method refresh in my view model:

```
fun refresh() {
    brewerDataSourceFactory.refresh()
}
```

In my case i'm using retrofit to fetch data from server

> ItemResponse is the object which i'm getting from server (Retrofit)

```
class DataSourceFactory : DataSource.Factory<Int, ItemResponse>() {

    lateinit var dataSource: DataSource
    var dataSourceLiveData: MutableLiveData<DataSource> =
        MutableLiveData<DataSource>()

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, ItemResponse> {

        dataSource = DataSource()
        dataSourceLiveData.postValue(dataSource)
        return dataSource

    }

    fun refresh() {
        dataSourceLiveData.value?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

In my DataSource is defined like following:

> `class DataSource : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, ItemResponse>`

I hope it helps!

Comment: In my case, is not working... what am I doing wrong? Or what could be the edge cases? I posted a similar question because I am still not getting able to refresh data from a paginated recyclerView... Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Amg91. 

Could you post your source code? 
So we can check it out.

Comment: Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62840390/6723193