# android paging how to refresh data？

Tags: android, android-paging

When the dataSource change ,How to refresh the layout? if you know,please tell me,thank you.

```
adapter = new CollectAdapter(context, CollectionFragment.this);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(8) 
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false) 
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(8)
            .build();
    liveData = new LivePagedListBuilder(new DataSourceFactory(), config).build();
    liveData.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Collection>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(PagedList<Collection> collections) {
            adapter.submitList(collections);
        }
    });
    recyvleView = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_collect);
    recyvleView.addItemDecoration(new RecycleViewItemDecoration(5, 5));
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyvleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyvleView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: RecyclerView item layout automatically changed when dataSource changed.

Comment: Data  changed,dataSource  how to chang?

Comment: You want to know how to change dataSource?

Comment: Data is from sqlite,sqlite data changed,I want to konw how  to change dataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the dataSource by calling invalidate method:

```
livedata.value.dataSource.invalidate()
```

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074882/how-to-implement-swiperefreshlayout-with-the-new-paging-library/54166401#54166401

Comment: also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66222791/3496570

Answer (score 1):

An improvement of Ahmed Garhy answer, which restricts spamming swiping. Still this is tricky solution but provides a bit different UX.

```
swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
  movieListAdapter.refresh()
  swiperefresh.isRefreshing = false
}
```

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            //this reveals RV when loading is complete
            rv_list.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            ///this keeps indicating that data is refreshing now
            progress_bar.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            //this turns off swipeRefresh while updating
            swipe_refresh.isEnabled = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
        }
    }
```