# Recycler chat Pagination add new message at top

Tags: java, android, sql, android-recyclerview, pagination

I am working on a chat app where I need to show reverse pagination and show the user's previous chat when the user scrolls up.

I am first loading data from `SQLite` database to show the last 10 messages of the user.

```
public Cursor getLimitUserChat(String UserID,int nextChat){
    Log.d(TAG,"Get Single Row Running= ID "+UserID);
    database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " Where "+ RECEIVER_USERID +"="+ UserID+" ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET "+nextChat,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Then I add a cursor to the custom `ArrayList`

```
private  class databaseAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    boolean checkDB_Exist,chatItemsCounts;
    private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Database Function "+databaseChatValue);
        if (databaseChatValue == 0){
            message.clear();
        }
        recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();


        //chatCursor=chat_database.getUserChat(UserID_Intent);
        chatCount = chat_database.getUserChatCount(UserID_Intent);
        chatCursor=chat_database.getLimitUserChat(UserID_Intent,databaseChatValue);
        checkDB_Exist=functions.DatabaseExist(getActivity(),"CHAT_DATABASE.DB");
        chatItemsCounts=chatCursor.getCount()>0;
        chatCursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Cursor "+ chatCursor.getCount());
        Log.d(TAG,"Total Chat Counts "+chatCount);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (checkDB_Exist && chatCursor.getCount()>0 && chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID")).equals(UserID_Intent)) {
            chatCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                database_rowID = chatCursor.getInt(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                database_userID = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_ID"));
                database_RoomName = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ROOM_NAME"));
                database_ReceiverID = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID"));
                database_MessageType = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MESSAGE_TYPE"));
                database_Message = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_MESSAGE"));
                database_MsgFrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_NAME"));
                database_MsgTo = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_NAME"));
                database_TimeStamp = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("TIME_STAMP"));
                database_FCMfrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_TOKEN"));
                database_FCMto = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_TOKEN"));
                database_LocalPath = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("DOWNLOADED_AT"));
                database_PhoneFrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MY_PHONE"));
                database_PhoneTo = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("OTHER_PHONE"));

                Log.d(TAG, "Value Of Database Message String = " + database_Message);
                Log.d(TAG, "Row ID of Database " + database_rowID);
                // Check Message Type
                if (true) {

                    if (database_MessageType.equals("Image")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Image");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Row ID of Database " + database_rowID);
                        Chat_Wrapper image = new Chat_Wrapper(null, database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(image);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("GIF")) {
                        Chat_Wrapper image = new Chat_Wrapper(null, database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(image);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Video") || (database_MessageType.equals("Youtube_Video"))) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Video");
                        Chat_Wrapper Video = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, database_Message, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Video);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Audio")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Audio");
                        Chat_Wrapper Audio = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, database_Message, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Audio);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Documents")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Documents");
                        Chat_Wrapper Docs = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, null, database_Message, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Docs);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Location")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Location");
                        Chat_Wrapper Location = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, null, null, database_Message, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Location);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Geofence")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Geofence");
                        Chat_Wrapper GeoFence = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Chat_TimeStamp, UserPhone_Intent, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, database_Message, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(GeoFence);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Contacts")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Contacts");
                        Chat_Wrapper Contacts = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, null, null, null, database_Message, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Contacts);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Online Media")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Online Media");
                        Chat_Wrapper Online_Media = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, database_Message, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(Online_Media);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Text")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Text");
                        Chat_Wrapper text = new Chat_Wrapper(database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
                        message.add(text);
                    } else if (database_MessageType.equals("Google_Search")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Google Search");
                        List<String> gSearch = new ArrayList<>();
                        gSearch.add(database_Message);
                        Chat_Wrapper GoogleSearch = new Chat_Wrapper(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, gSearch, database_rowID);
                        message.add(GoogleSearch);
                    }
                }
                }
                while (chatCursor.moveToNext()) ;
                Room_Name_Intent = database_RoomName;
                chatCursor.close();
                boolean value = chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
                Log.d(TAG, "Value Of Database Close or Not " + value);
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (message.size()>2){
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size()-1);
        }else {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.getItemCount());
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Database  "+database_OFFSET);
        database_OFFSET +=10;
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Database  "+database_OFFSET);
    }
}
```

I also have made `RecyclerView` and `LayoutManager` settings like this

```
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

At first load, it fetches total 10 result from the local database but as soon as it loads into screen first, it loads in the correct order (Latest message at the end and older at the top). But `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll at bottom automatically. At the start, it loads from the top and when I scroll it calls the following method.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
            Log.d(TAG,"Hello I am scrolling screen ");
            isScrolling = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        currentVisible = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        TotalItems = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        scrolledOutItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int check = TotalItems - currentVisible+scrolledOutItems;
        Log.d(TAG,"Current Visible = "+currentVisible+" Total = "+TotalItems+" Scrolled Out Items = "+scrolledOutItems+" Check = "+check);

        if (isScrolling && TotalItems == currentVisible + scrolledOutItems ){
            Log.d(TAG,"Fetch Data Now "+databaseChatValue);
            if (chatCount > databaseChatValue){
                Log.d(TAG,"Total item count is more than database = "+chatCount +" "+databaseChatValue);
                new databaseAsync().execute();
                isScrolling = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And loads another into screen.

***Issues In Code***

- When Set `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` without `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` pagination works at bottom of last message and also new message adds at bottom

  - When Set `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);` pagination works as required but new message stacked at top of the oldest message.

[image]

**Update** :I notice my newest message has index number in array [0] and my last message after scrolls to oldest message [21]. So when i typed new message into my chat box it assign to [22] in array and shows above oldest message at top not at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: i suggest you to use new Android paging library instead of using scroll listener. It is highly satisfying. Then you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074882/how-to-implement-swiperefreshlayout-with-the-new-paging-library this answer and modify it for your application.

Comment: @ErginErsoy It's not an paging issue. As user said paging works correctly but there is data showing wrong place its more of array and sqlite issue than paging

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this [TwoWay-Endless RecyclerView](https://github.com/abbasshah17/TwoWay-EndlessRecyclerView).

Comment: @Abbas You right but can you let me know how to do this according to my code

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add new item into your chat screen(arraylist) dont go with `message.add(Video);` instead add item at 0 position like this `message.add(0,Video);` which will add items at bottom of screen(top of array list) than adding top of the screen(last of array list). It will be add into start position of array i.e. `[0]` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Now I think, the problem is with your database query. I assume that whenever a new message is typed, it is stored in the database with the highest `ID` that makes it the latest in your database table organization. Hence, the `getLimitUserChat` should never return the latest message if you are setting the offset correctly.

---

I do not know what the `dataBaseAsync.execute` function do. I assume, it adds more elements into the `ArrayList` and calls the `notifyDateSetChanged`.

Hence the data should be populated in your `RecyclerView` in proper order if the addition of the newly fetched data to the `ArrayList` is correct. However, you might also notice that each time new paginated data is adding, your `RecyclerView` might scroll to the bottom as the reverse layout is enabled - which you might not want for a chat application.

Hence to keep the `RecyclerView` at the same place before loading new data you need to save the state of the `RecyclerView` and restore the state when the new data is fetched. Here is the code for storing the `RecyclerView` state and getting back into the same state.

```
// Save state
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();

// Restore state
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```

And I would like to suggest you set the `LayoutManager` like the following.

```
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please double check if the `ArrayList` is populated correctly (i.e. new data at the top of the list and older data at the bottom).

Hope that helps!

Please remove the following from your `onPostExecute`.

```
if (message.size() > 2){
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size()-1);
} else {
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.getItemCount());
}
```

And also add necessary `null` checkings in the `preExecute`.

Comment: `dataBaseAsync` is AsyncTask to get entries from SQLite database and its one where i am getting and adding data to arraylist from database

Comment: I understand, please check if the data are added correctly as I mentioned in my answer. Let me know if the answer helps. :)

Comment: My new data still adding above old messages. I saved recycler state at `PreExecute` of AsyncTask and restore at `postexecute`.

Comment: Did you do the changes that I have suggested for the layout manager as well? And yes, please post your code that adds new items in the `ArrayList` and does the pagination.

Comment: Please check i update code with complete databaseAsync where i am adding data at first load and also with pagination

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you please take a look? I am in the middle of debugging your code and will post update if I get something wrong again.

Comment: I want to see your `getLimitUserChat` function as well. This should be an ordered query.

Comment: I just typed new message which take screen to top of oldest message and add there. `getLimitUserChat` is same as you can see in SQL query above its returning cursor

Comment: What is the database query that you are using for your paginated data fetching?

Comment: check updated code with `getLimitUserChat` function

Comment: Yes, I have checked that already. Please allow me some time. :)

Comment: No its not with database cuz if i setreverseLayout(false); then i will add new item at bottom of the screen and i am not fetching new items from database while user is online i am showing items from firebase database then make a copy into local database also.

Comment: Now are you sure when you are setting `reverseLayout(true)` it's showing the latest message at the bottom? Because, your previous comment is contradictory.

Comment: not at the bottom at the top of older message if setreverselayout
(true)

Comment: i just notice issue this might cause the error. I remove `reverseLayout(true)` then pagination loads at bottom when scrolls and when add `reverseLayout(true)` and remove `setStackFromEnd` then it works as i want but new messages add at the top of the screen. Any idea why this happening

Comment: array list loads at `[0]` = latest message and older message with higher ID and when i type new message it gets highest ID.